# 2D Array manipulation in Java

Tags: java, arrays, oop, multidimensional-array

I am trying to work with this a two dimensional array, that represents greyscale of an image... I want to pixelate the image by averaging 2x2 blocks and replacing each value by the average of the 2x2 grid... for example,
if the input is the array

```
   2,  4, 31, 31   
   3,  3, 21, 41
   1,  2, 10, 20
   3,  2, 20, 30
```

then you start by looking at the first 2x2 sub-array (from the top-left)

```
   2,  4
   3,  3
```

and find the average of this sub-array (which is (2+4+3+3)/4 = 3). In the returned array, the first 2x2 sub-array will then be

```
   3,  3
   3,  3
```

We then look at the next 2x2 block

```
   31,  31
   21,  41
```

with average 31, The next 2x2 block in the output will be

```
   31,  31
   31,  31
```

I am wondering what approach would best solve this problem. Not too sure how to solve it... Thanks in advance

Comment: [What have you tried](http://whathaveyoutried.com)?

Answer (score 2):

You can declare a multi-dimensional array in Java very easily:

```
double matrix[][] = new double[size][size];
```

You can then address individual elements using standard subscripting. For example:

```
int row = 2;
int col = 3;
double val = matrix[row][col]; // etc.
matrix[row][col] = 7;
```

Technically, however, Java does not have multi-dimensional arrays. Instead, it has arrays of arrays. Accessing multi-dimensional array elements can be a bit slower than accessing a (single-dimensional) array. You can always write your own `Matrix` class that maintains values as a single array and computes subscripts from matrix coordinates. I'm not sure whether, in terms of performance, this is worth it. Also, there are plenty of matrix packages available for Java. A web search for *java matrix packages* turns up lots of good-quality hits. They are all probably overkill for what you are trying to do.